# How to 'postMessage' from a Chrome Extension page to another domain opened in a pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects, postmessage

I have this code in a JS file imported into an HTML page of my Chrome Extension:

```
const pathTsr_1 = "../tsr/tsr_templates/mailbox_quota.txt";
const myTsr = new XMLHttpRequest();
myTsr.open("GET", pathTsr_1);
myTsr.send();

myTsr.addEventListener("load", () => {

    const linka = myTsr.responseText;

    document.getElementById("linkTSR_BT").addEventListener("click", () => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(linka);
        var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
        tooltip.innerHTML = "COPIED!";
    });

    document.getElementById("linkTSR_BT_TSR").addEventListener("click", () => {
        window.receiver = window.open('https://teams.somepage.com/share?', 'ms-teams-share-popup', 'width=700,height=600');
        window.receiver.addEventListener("load", () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.receiver.postMessage(linka, chrome.runtime.getURL(""));
            }, 1000); // Delay by 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
        });
        //alert(myMessage);
    });
});

function outFunc() {
    document.getElementById("myTooltip").innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

In a content script that gets injected into domain "teams.somepage.com" (which gets injected into the popup opened above), I have this code:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    // Check the origin of the received message to make sure it's from the correct domain
    if (event.origin !== "https://teams.somepage.com") return;
    //alert(event);
    // Find the compose box element
    const compBox = document.querySelector("#share-form-compose > p");
    // Send text into compose box
    //alert(JSON.stringify(event.data));
    compBox.textContent = event.data;
});
```

I am consistently getting console errors:
"Cannot set properties of null"

It seems the message does not get passed from the Extension page into the pop-up.
I have tried everything I can think of. What am I missing?

Comment: The line that is causing the error is ```compBox.textContent = event.data;```. But if I change to ```compBox.textContent = "test123";``` then the text "test123" gets inserted into the compose box, so that code finds the ```"#share-form-compose > p"```. When I console.log the ```event.data``` I do not get the intended message. Sometimes shows as ```undefined``` other times as ```[Object object]``` and. If I use ```JSON.stringify``` when it shows as  ```[Object object]``` it shows a bunch of info from browser like position of mouse, and other technical stuff. ```toolTip``` works ok I can see it.

Comment: Replace `chrome.runtime.getURL("")` with '*' or use the origin of the site you open. Note that web messaging can be intercepted by the site so you may want to use chrome.storage instead or chrome.runtime.sendMessage via a relay in the background script.

Comment: So using ```chrome.runtime.sendMessage``` instead of ```postMessage``` would be better? 
Would that require me to transfer the code from the HTML Javascript code to the "background.js" of the extension?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Note that chrome.storage is simpler as it doesn't require a background relay.